# Google Map is not Working in Android after downloading the apk from play store

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi Everyone i am working on a map application.My problem is when i am creating the release build and installing this build on my real device map is loading but after uploading the same build to play store and downloading to my real device now Google map is not loading getting the error

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.

04-25 18:05:27.159 10524-10703/? E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: AIz~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~0
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>)
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this Authorization Failure? i have added SHA1 for release in `Google API's console`. I also tried for new key but No Luck. I already spend 2 days on Stackoverflow but no luck.

Comment: is that GoogleMaps enabled in Google developers console ?

Comment: yes google map api is enable that's why it is working before uploading

Comment: @ShubhamJain I am having the same issue too actually.  Take a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79405933 and see if it matches yours and also please star and add any extra info!!!

Comment: Im also facing same issue, @shubhamJain did you resolved the issue? got any solution on it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a new GEO API Key in AndroidManifest.xml different than the one you use during development. Upload the app with new key without running in dev mode and it will work fine.

Comment: as i already mentioned that i have tried with new key but it is also not working